# How do I install GTK+ >=3.8.7 development headers on 14.04 so that goffice's configure script recognizes it?

Tags: 14.04, compiling, gtk

In a Ubuntu 14.04 Travis CI instance I have been trying to build goffice from source code. I have run:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep -y goffice gnumeric
sudo apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev
```

yet still I get the build error shown in this [build log](https://travis-ci.org/fusion809/Gnumeric.AppImage/builds/180914261#L2445), or:

```
checking for GTK... no
configure: error: Package requirements (
    gtk+-3.0        >= 3.8.7
) were not met:
No package 'gtk+-3.0' found
```

I know this question is similar to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/856434/how-do-i-install-gtk-3-8-7-development-headers-on-ubuntu-12-04-so-that-goffic) of mine, but I believe this one is distinct as the version of libgtk-3-dev in the Trusty repo (3.10.8) is >3.8.7, unlike that in the Precise repos (3.4.1). Hence it is not surprising that I get errors on Precise but it is surprising that I get this build error on Trusty. I have tried installing the `gnome3-team/gnome3` and `gnome3-team/gnome3-staging` PPAs (and running `sudo apt-get update`) before installing `libgtk-3-dev` and other `goffice` build dependencies, in case it makes it difference but the build still fails giving the same error.

Comment: Have you installed a version of gtk3 outside of the package management system? what do `pkg-config --modversion gtk+-3.0` and `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` say?

Comment: No I haven't. See https://travis-ci.org/fusion809/Gnumeric.AppImage#L1726 for the output.